# How to subscribe to NFT transfers in solana py?

Tags: nft, transfer, python, subscription

I'm using `solana` library in python to write a program that subscribe to an account and show balance changes in real time.

```
import asyncio
from asyncstdlib import enumerate
from solana.rpc.websocket_api import connect

async def main():
    async with connect("wss://api.devnet.solana.com") as websocket:
        await websocket.logs_subscribe()
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        subscription_id = first_resp[0].result
        next_resp = await websocket.recv()
        print(next_resp)
        await websocket.logs_unsubscribe(subscription_id)

    # Alternatively, use the client as an infinite asynchronous iterator:
    async with connect("wss://api.devnet.solana.com") as websocket:
        await websocket.logs_subscribe()
        first_resp = await websocket.recv()
        subscription_id = first_resp[0].result
        async for idx, msg in enumerate(websocket):
            if idx == 3:
                break
            print(msg)
        await websocket.logs_unsubscribe(subscription_id)

asyncio.run(main())
```

(This is the code I pasted from [here](https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/))

When I send NFT tokens to the wallet this program is listening to, it does not receive any notification. I think that's because NFTs are not actually sent to this account, but to the another account which it is its owner. But how can receive notification for those kind of transfers too?